# Decoding and encoding a certain portion of a String into X'es?

Tags: java

I have to complete a program where the criteria is as follows:

- Objects created from the *Code* class have one parameter: (String code)
- The *Code* class has two methods: hide(int p1, int p2) and recover(int p1, int p2).
- Hiding replaces all of the characters within the index range of p1 to p2 with "XXXX..."
- Recovering replaces all of the X'es with the original text.

I am completely stumped as to how to approach this. I have tried multiple approaches, but I always wind up overcomplicating it and confusing myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest showing us what you have done, and we can help you from there.

Comment: Post one of your better attempts, or at least ask some specific questions.  In other words, what have you tried, and why did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class and its method replace